# Is it possible to disable NoScripts shortcut keys in TBB?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Apparently pressing T while hovering over the NoScripts icon will grant temporary script permissions to the active tab. This seems to offer virtually negligible convenience at the cost of a potential human error that could expose the user. Is it possible to disable this shortcut or at least make it prompt me before granting permissions?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather odd, NoScript doesn't appear to have "T" set as shortcut for temporarily allowing script by default.

If it is enabled, you should be able to disable it via:

1. type about:config in url bar and hit enter
2. search for noscript.keys.tempAllowPage
3. ensure value is set to an empty string